# Multi-Indexed fillna in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data, multi-index

I have a multi-indexed dataframe and I'm looking to backfill missing values within a group. The dataframe I have currently looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
                'group': ['group_a'] * 7 + ['group_b'] * 3 + ['group_c'] * 2,
                'Date': ["2013-06-11",
                        "2013-07-02",
                        "2013-07-09",
                        "2013-07-30",
                        "2013-08-06",
                        "2013-09-03",
                        "2013-10-01",
                        "2013-07-09",
                        "2013-08-06",
                        "2013-09-03",
                        "2013-07-09",
                        "2013-09-03"],
                 'Value': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,  9,  4, 40, 18, np.nan, np.nan, 5, np.nan, 2]})

df.Date = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).date())
df = df.set_index(['group', 'Date'])
```

I'm trying to get a dataframe that backfills the missing values within the group. 
Like this:

```
Group   Date        Value
group_a 2013-06-11      9
        2013-07-02      9
        2013-07-09      9
        2013-07-30      9
        2013-08-06      4
        2013-09-03     40
        2013-10-01     18
group_b 2013-07-09      5
        2013-08-06      5
        2013-09-03      5
group_c 2013-07-09      2
        2013-09-03      2
```

I tried using `pd.fillna('Value', inplace=True)`, but I get a warning on setting a value on copy, which I've since figured out is related to the presence of the multi-index. Is there a way to make fillna work for multi-indexed rows? Also, ideally I'd be able to apply the fillna to only one column and not the entire dataframe.

Any insight on this would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `groupby(level=0)` then `bfill` and `update`:

```
df.update(df.groupby(level=0).bfill())
df
```

Note: `update` changes `df` inplace.

[image]

#### Other alternatives

```
df = df.groupby(level='group').bfill()

df = df.unstack(0).bfill().stack().swaplevel(0, 1).reindex_like(df)
```

#### Column specific

```
df.Value = df.groupby(level=0).Value.bfill()
```

Comment: That's on your end.  Start off with `df = df.copy()`.

Comment: @Charles I updated my post, at the end, I have a column specific section.