# How to fill values based on data present in column and an array? Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Lets say I have dataframe with nans in each group like

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'data':[0,1,2,0,np.nan,2,np.nan,0,1],'group':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]})
```

and a numpy array like

```
x = np.array([0,1,2])
```

Now based on groups how to fill the missing values that are in the numpy array I have i.e

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'data':[0,1,2,0,1,2,2,0,1],'group':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]})
```

```
      data   group
0     0      1
1     1      1
2     2      1
3     0      2
4     1      2
5     2      2
6     2      3
7     0      3
8     1      3
```

Let me explain a bit of how the data should be filled. Consider the group 2. The values of `data` are 0,np.nan,2 . The `np.nan` is the missing value from the array `[0,1,2]`. So the data to be filled inplace of nan is `1`.

For multiple nan values, take a group for example that has data [np.nan,0,np.nan] now the values to be filled in place of nan are 1 and 2. resulting in `[1,0,2]`.

Comment: Fill how? By mean of group or something? Or is like every group has exactly three numbers - 0,1,2?

Comment: Yes, I will have maximum three rows. So the data should be filled with missing data in the `data` and present in numpy array. If there are 2 values missing then the they should be filled be randomly.

Comment: why we need group by here ....

Comment: Could there be less than 3 elems in a  group?

Comment: @Wen if you could do that without group I'm more curious

Comment: @ Divakar no 3 elems in a group is compulsary I mean are always present

Comment: You come from the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46937010/filling-missing-time-values-in-a-multi-indexed-dataframe , right ? I posted an answer there

Comment: What happens if you have more than 3 nans in a row? Another question - reasonably how many NaNs can I expect per group?

Comment: As I said earlier in the comments there will be only 3 rows in each group and three rows are always present. There can be maximum of three nans.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First find value which miss and then add it to `fillna`:

```
def f(y):
    a = list(set(x)-set(y))
    a = 1 if len(a) == 0 else a[0]
    y = y.fillna(a)
    return (y)

df['data'] = df.groupby('group')['data'].apply(f).astype(int)
print (df)
   data  group
0     0      1
1     1      1
2     2      1
3     0      2
4     1      2
5     2      2
6     2      3
7     0      3
8     1      3
```

EDIT:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'data':[0,1,2,0,np.nan,2,np.nan,np.nan,1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                   'group':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4]})
x = np.array([0,1,2])
print (df)
    data  group
0    0.0      1
1    1.0      1
2    2.0      1
3    0.0      2
4    NaN      2
5    2.0      2
6    NaN      3
7    NaN      3
8    1.0      3
9    NaN      4
10   NaN      4
11   NaN      4
```

---

```
def f(y):
    a = list(set(x)-set(y))
    if len(a) == 1:
        return y.fillna(a[0])
    elif len(a) == 2:
        return y.fillna(a[0], limit=1).fillna(a[1])
    elif len(a) == 3:
        y = pd.Series(x, index=y.index)
        return y
    else:
        return y

df['data'] = df.groupby('group')['data'].apply(f).astype(int)
print (df)
    data  group
0      0      1
1      1      1
2      2      1
3      0      2
4      1      2
5      2      2
6      0      3
7      2      3
8      1      3
9      0      4
10     1      4
11     2      4
```

Comment: Sir do try this for multiple nans in one group na.

Comment: I am doing on it

Comment: @Bharathshetty It seems like jez understood your question better than I did. I think I'll leave it to him to answer your Q.

Comment: Well @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I updated my question. Hope you find that information usefull.

Comment: Really hard, please check my solution.

Comment: Sir really nice solution. My bad I had changed the array x to some other values.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - Thanks